# How to make video auto play in every browser for Shopify website

Tags: shopify

I'm using the retina theme for the Shopify site. I'm using video on my home page but it's not autoplay in the chrome. another browser it's playing well...please tell me to need to customize code for autoplay in the chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome can autoplay the videos with sound off, so you'll need to add muted attribute.

```
<video autoplay muted>
...
</video>
```

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes